# is it possible to use ECDSA signature with SHA256 in PDF 1.4?

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfbox

we are trying to sign generated pdf (pdf version 1.4), I could not find any standard which says ECDSA is supported in PDF 1.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### In short

There are no normative requirements concerning allowed signature algorithms in PDF 1.4. Furthermore, PDF 1.4 does not yet contain recommendations for interoperable signatures.

The PDF 2.0 standard in its section on "Signature interoperability" considers SHA256withECDSA only interoperable from PDF 2.0 onwards.

### In detail

First of all, PDF versions before 1.7 are not properly standardized, the first standardized generic PDF version is 1.7 as ISO 32000-1:2008.

Ok, there are the Adobe PDF References for the PDF versions up to 1.7; but [Adobe personal explained](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/PJL-commands-in-pdf-files-OK-tp2163248p2163251.html) on the iText mailing list that *PDF References aren't "normative" in nature - they don't (usually) make final, definitive statements - just sort of general ones.* Thus, you could not independently determine whether a given statement is true for a given PDF version, Adobe could later decree that the opposite was the case.

Nonetheless the PDF Reference 1.4 serves as a basis for the specification of PDF/A-1 as ISO 19005-1:2005 which to a certain degree elevates this PDF Reference to a semi-normative level. Thus, let us work under the assumption that PDF 1.4 is indeed "specified" by the PDF Reference 1.4.

Unfortunately, though, the PDF Reference 1.4 does not restrict the format of the signature very much:

> The signature may be purely mathematical, such as a
>   public/private-key encrypted document digest, or it may be a biometric form of
>   identification such as a handwritten signature, fingerprint, or retinal scan. The
>   specific form of authentication used is implemented by a plug-in *signature
>   handler*.

So in PDF 1.4 it was up to the *signature handler* in question to decide what was allowed and what not, this was not part of the "standard".

*As indicated by [Lonzak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47470057/1729265) - thanks for the reminder - the PDF Reference 1.4 after the quote above continues and says "The specification for public-key digital signature authentication is available in
the Adobe document PDF Public-Key Digital Signature and Encryption Specification
(see the Bibliography)."*

*At first glance it appears like the document might contain the information sought. While it indeed contains some more details than the PDF reference, e.g. which **SubFilter** values correspond to PKCS#1 or PKCS#7 signature values and what data, if any, shall be embedded in the PKCS#7 to be signed, it does* not *describe which signature and hashing algorithms are allowed in PKCS#7 containers. Thus, unfortunately this document does not help in the question at hand.*

This corresponds to the point of view of the PDF Association, cf. their [Technical Note 6](https://www.pdfa.org/publication/technical-note-tn0006-digital-signatures-in-pdfa-1/):

> PDF Reference 1.4 defines how digital signatures are to be embedded into a document. There are aspects of the digital signature that are impacted by the PDF/A-1 standard, e.g. fonts and colors. However, the standard does not make any statements about the semantics, i.e. on how signatures are created and validated. The semantics of digital signatures is left up to the corresponding signature handlers which are uniquely identified by registered names.

As a result, the Technical Note 6 continues by deriving these *semantics* from later PDF References.

Indeed, starting with PDF Reference 1.5 there are sections "Signature Interoperability" which give more and more concrete guide lines for interoperable PDF signatures.

Beware though, these guide lines still are not general requirements.

According to the PDF 2.0 specification ISO 32000-2:2017, the algorithm restrictions by PDF version **for the interoperable signatures** are:

[image: screenshot]

This considers your SHA256withECDSA signatures not interoperable before PDF 2.0!

Comment: What Amedee says.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what MKL said there was a bit more information on digital signatures in PDF 1.4, it was however 'outsourced' to another file as you can read in the PDF 1.4 spec: "The **specification** for public-key digital signature authentication is available in the Adobe document‚ *PDF Public-Key Digital Signature and Encryption Specification*’.“

In the introduction you can read the following:

> "This specification describes a standard syntax for the storage of
> data in the signature dictionary and the encryption dictionary of
> plug-ins that use public-key technology. A degree of interoperability
> of signed and encrypted PDF files across plug-ins and over time should
> be possible by using a standardized syntax (see Signature and
> Encryption Handler Interoperability).

But of course as written by mkl there are no mentions of specific ECDSA algorithms or such. The above mentioned document is not available anymore since it became part of PDF 1.5 specification. So if you want to know exactly what was supported in 1.4 you can read the PDF 1.5 specification OR even ISO 32000-1 itself for that information. Each feature is "tagged" with the specific version in which it was introduced.

In the adobe pdf specification forum there is a similar [question](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/587267) (support for newer signature types in general) which you may find interesting (because the adobe specification lead answered himself):

> As far as hashing for digital signatures, there are no technical (file
> format) restrictions about the use of newer algorithms that still fall
> into the PDF standard.
>
> HOWEVER, you there is also no expectation that a "conforming reader"
> will be able to process them, as it need only process those things in
> PDF 1.4.  (Adobe Reader doesn't differentiate in that matter, but
> someone else might).

**So in a nutshell you may use newer signature standards in PDF 1.4 however you may not know how a reader deals with it. In case of the adobe reader it would be supported but for 3rd party readers you don't know.**

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I downloaded the referenced document (not easy to find after Adobe put it off its site) and added to my answer accordingly. Unfortunately, as you already indicated, it does not go into valid signature or hashing algorithms for pkcs7-detached signatures.